# How can I set state for a dictionary nested inside a list in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, setstate

Here is my code below..
I want to set the sate of data( present inside datasets) to user defined value

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state={
        value:'',
        set:[],
        count:0,
        data: {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
            datasets:[ {
                data: [10,20,30,40]
            }]
        },
       
    }
}
```

I tried the below code but it didn't work

```
 this.setState(prevState => {
    return{
        datas: {...prevState.datas,datasetss: {...prevState.datas.datasetss[0], data [...prevState.datas.datasetss[0].data,prevState.value]}
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: is typo intended? datasets vs datasetss

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure that I understood what you want, but here you go an snippet for updating a nested property, I hope that it works for you

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    value: "",
    set: [],
    count: 0,
    data: {
      labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [10, 20, 30, 40]
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData((currentData) => {
        const newData = { ...currentData };
        newData.data.datasets[0].data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        return newData;
      });
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 1)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
  // Getting the initial/ prev values for data
  const newState = {...this.state.data.datasets[0]};
  // Add the new value to data. Here I am adding 50 and 60    
  newState.data.push(50, 60);
  // Set the state using useState
  this.setState({newState});
```